# ORA-56903: sys_op_pivot function is not allowed here in Oracle 19 not in 12c

Tags: group-by, pivot, grouping-sets

some views run under Oracle 12c FINISHED CORRECTLY (SELECT WITH GROUP BY GROUPING SETS in this view AND PIVOT IN THIS VIEW OR VIEW USED BY IT). When same views are run under Oracle 19 error  ORA-56903: sys_op_pivot function is not allowed here is thrown.  sys_op_pivot is not used directly int this view and I cna't remove it as sugested by error description.
Thanks in advance.
Best regards

I have run all referenced views and tables which this views used and that view return data correctly to see that error is not coused by referenced views or tables.